# Delete the asterisk character

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I wrote this code to look through my worksheet and delete any row where the phrase "(asterisk)Start(asterisk)" is found. However, I think the asterisk character is being recognized differently. How could I update this code to look for the literal asterisk character and delete any line with an instance of this character?

```
Sub Example()

    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim cRow As Long, lastRow As Long
    lastRow = Worksheets("Formula").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
    With Worksheets("Formula").Range("A1", Worksheets("Formula").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        Do
            Set c = .Find(What:="*Start*", After:=[A1], LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns _
            , SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False)
            If Not c Is Nothing Then
                cRow = c.row
                c.EntireRow.Delete
            End If
         Loop While Not c Is Nothing And cRow < lastRow
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: `What:="~*Start~*",` may be worth trying, as the tilde character (`~`) indicates the next character should be interpreted *literally* instead of as a wildcard.

Comment: I'm unclear why `And cRow < lastRow` is necessary. Are there cells containing `*Start*` below the last populated row in column A that should not be deleted? If there are, then lastrow needs to compensate for the rows that are deleted because everything gets shifted up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Escape it with `~` :

```
Set c = .Find(What:="~*Start~*", After:=[A1], LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns _
    , SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can escape the wildcard `*` asterisk using a tilde `~` before it:

```
Set c = .Find(What:="~*Start~*", After:=[A1], LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns _
        , SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False)
```